How do I remove these drawers?
I'm feeling pretty silly right now. I had a bathroom renovation a year or so ago and need to remove the drawers of my vanity to do some routine inspection of the water hoses behind connecting the sink to the mains.
The problem is that I cannot figure out how the drawers come out. They don't lift or budge in any direction, even when pulled out as far as they'll go. The runners don't seem to have any obvious mechanism for removal (I have no idea what the plastic tab or metal spiky bit are for, but as far as I can tell they do not related to removing the drawers):


Can anyone tell me what this style of drawer runner is called and how to remove them?
Update
Thanks to Aloysius for providing the answer: removing the small screws at the front of the runner. I hadn't considered them because I assumed there more more at the back that I couldn't get to and therefore that that part of the runner would come out with the drawer.
Once those screws were removed, I could lift up the front of the drawer then pull it forward. Directly behind the screw is a much stronger kind of plug that slots into the drawer:

And the back of the runner has a spike that secures the back of the drawer:


The black handle is a hint

Is the drawer pulled all the way out?

@RMDman yes, all the way out.

@DIY75 like I said, the plastic tab doesn't seem to do anything but feel free to enlighten me.

pull it out while opening drawer

@DIY75 As you can see from the photos, it's at the front of the runner, not the back. Even if I could take it out (it doesn't budge in any way) it would have zero impact on what's happening at the back of the drawer runner.

The runners don't seem to have any obvious mechanism for removal ... what about the screw?

What is underneath that drawer? Is it something you can open to have a look upwards at the rest of the runner?

"I had a bathroom renovation a year or so ago" Is the company still in business? If so, they may be able to tell you how to take the drawers out. Or the approval paperwork you got from them may say what kind of slides they are; tell us the slide manufacturer and model and we may be able to guide you specifically.

Crawl underneath and look up.   Maybe the answer is there.

Undo the screws that fasten the tracks to the bottoms of the drawer sides. The drawer should come off the top of the rails.
(I feel like there are parts missing, but that’s not important at this point.)

I suspect that Aloysius is referring to the tiny screw holding the metal to the wood on the right side of the slide in the first picture, not the larger "screw" on the left side of the slide: that large "screw" is actually a cam for holding the wood pieces of the drawer box together, probably not for holding the slide to the drawer box.

@Aloysius that was it, thanks very much! I feel like a dolt for not realizing but had reasonably good reasons for not doing so. Added the answer with pics to original post.
